Calculating the minimum number of moves for an N*N number puzzle where you can swap any two tiles in one move
I've seen similar posts on the classic 8 or 15 number puzzles, where they have a blank tile and you can swap it with any orthogonally adjacent tile in a single move, but the puzzle I'm thinking of does not have a blank tile (so it has N*N as its number instead), and you can move any two tiles, so they don't necessarily have to be orthogonally adjacent. I wasn't able to find any information on calculating the minimum number of moves to solve a puzzle of this type so I'm hoping someone has some ideas!
If I understand correctly, the upper bound for this sort of puzzle would be N*N-1 as each move except for the final move would only put a single tile into its correct state, and the lower bound would be 1, as all but 2 tiles would already be in their proper place and you just have to swap those to complete it, but I don't know the best way of calculating the minimum number of moves for any given puzzle.
I'd like to be able to calculate the minimum number of moves because I plan on using image segments instead of numbers inside of the tiles, with the goal being to properly recombine the image, and because of this you will be more likely to put a tile in an incorrect spot, so I'd like to have the minimum number as a 'benchmark' you can compare with.

Actually, lower bound is $0$, if you're given the configuration where everything is already in place.

Sorry, I should've mentioned that during the puzzle creation / randomization, it won't accept already solved puzzles :)

You could just have the computer solve it. Unlike the human solver, it already knows where each piece belongs. If it always places at least one piece correctly on every swap, then regardless of the order in which it is solved the solution will be optimal, so the number of moves used will always be the same and be the number you want. A simple way is to solve the tiles in order - if tile 1 is not yet solved, swap it with the tile at location 1 to solve it, then do the same with tile 2, tile 3, etc

Label your pieces $1, 2, ..., M$.
Then you can represent your scrambled puzzle as a permutation. For example:
$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc}1&2&3&4&5&6&7\\6&7&3&1&5&4&2\end{array}\right)$$
This is saying that piece 6 is in 1's correct position. Piece 7 is in 2's correct position, etc.
Then we can detect the cycles:
$$1 \rightarrow 6\rightarrow 4\rightarrow 1$$
$$2 \rightarrow 7\rightarrow 2$$
$$3 \rightarrow 3$$
$$5 \rightarrow 5$$
If a cycle has $k$ elements, you will need $k-1$ swaps/moves to sort it.
So, to sort $M$ pieces, you'll need $M-c$ moves, where $c$ is the number of cycles in your permutation (each cycle prevents one move).

Thank you! This sort of thing is probably pretty basic, but it really helped me understand the problem that was eluding me before, and I was able to write some code that arrived at the desired solution.
